# Replace other vector elements with 0

Tags: r

Suppose you want to replace all elements of a vector conditionally. For example:

```
a <- c("A","T","G","A")
b <- c(1,4,1,5)
```

How would I create another vector c that would replace all "non-A" elements in b, with 0's?

desired result:

```
c <- c(1,0,0,5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy `b` and subset `c` by condition in `a`

```
c <- b
c[a!="A"] <- 0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what [`replace()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/replace.html) is designed for:

```
replace(b,a!='A',0);
## [1] 1 0 0 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Or another route:

```
c=ifelse(a=="A",b,0)
```

Comment: Sorry 17 < 18: "[<-"(b,a!="A",0)